# How do I use cheat codes in emulated PS1 games?

Tags: cheats, epsxe

How can I use Action Replay–type cheat codes for PS1 games that my computer (Windows) emulates?

I would like to play games I used to play when I was younger, such as Final Fantasy VIII, but I want to skip all the hours of grinding for experience. Codes would enable me to fully enjoy the game.

Answer (score 1):

The best one to use is probably [PEC](http://pec.duttke.de/).

There is a [nice guide](http://ngemu.com/threads/playstation-emulator-cheater-setup-guide.101186/) that runs through the setup and how to add it to ePSXE, as well as common issues (such as cheats not working, etc).

Comment: Please summarize the linked information here. That way, if the site is down, your answer is still valid and useful, without needing to rely on a different site.

Comment: @Frank [Here's an archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170317225842/http://ngemu.com/threads/playstation-emulator-cheater-setup-guide.101186/)